# How to test a command-line calculator with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a calculator app made with PHP running in command-line. How do I make a full code coverage test with PHPUnit?

I have tried to include the entire code into a function called test() and the function wrapped by a class called Calculator. Then I created a CalculatorTest file which contains CalculatorTest class. every time I type phpunit  CalculatorTest.php in command line I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of CalculatorTest::tearDown() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::tearDown(): void in C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\test_key_way\CalculatorTest.php on line 6.

I want to try another approach. Now my app code is no longer wrapped by function test() and class Calculator.
[This is my code for the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUSuq.jpg)

```
<?php

echo '|----calculator test for Key Way Group test----|' ."\n";

menu:

echo "|----Menu----| ". "\n";
echo "| 1. add ". "\n";
echo "| 2. subtract ". "\n";
echo "| 3. multiply ". "\n";
echo "| 4. divide ". "\n";
echo "| 5. Exit ". "\n";
$option = fwrite(STDOUT," choose operation: ");
$option = trim(fgets(STDIN));

if ($option == 1) 
{
   $in = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->add ");
   $in1 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $in2 = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->apply ");
   $in3 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $out = $in1 + $in3; 
   $op = "+";
 }
   elseif 
 ($option == 2) 
{
   $in = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->subtract ");
   $in1 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $in2 = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->apply ");
   $in3 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $out = $in1 - $in3; 
   $op = "-";
}

 elseif ($option == 3) 
{
   $in = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->multiply ");
   $in1 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $in2 = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->apply ");
   $in3 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $out = $in1 * $in3;
   $op = "*"; 
 }
  elseif 
 ($option == 4) 
{
   $in = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->divide ");
   $in1 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $in2 = fwrite(STDOUT, "|---->apply ");
   $in3 = trim(fgets(STDIN));
   $out = ($in1 / $in3);
   $op = "/";
     
}
 elseif ($option == 5) 
{
   exit;
 }
   else 
 {
  echo '           |---->wrong option!!!'."\n";
  goto menu;
 
}
 

echo "|---->The result is: $out. Explanation: $in1 $op $in3 = $out"."\n";  

goto menu;

?>
```

Comment: Not something I've tried, but see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700653/how-do-i-test-a-command-line-program-with-phpunit helps.

Comment: Just noticed something I haven't seen in years in code `goto menu;`!

Comment: Thanks Nigel. i have seen that  before posting this question, but I don;t find that answer as being complete. i don't know what to do further with that code, where to include it, what tu runin command line

Comment: @NigelRen, `goto` is happily present in sf messenger doctrine transport code base ))

Comment: @xmike, there are quite a few places it can be found and put to very good use, but there are also places where you wouldn't normally see them, quite often for very good reasons.