# mock non class function in phpunit test

Tags: php, php-7, phpunit

I have a raw PHP code for a for-each loop. I am using `php 7.2` and `PHPUnit 8`.

here is the filename `app.php` and code is given below: 
Here I have another call `CalculatorAPI()` which requires API call - need a mockup too.

```
$list = file_get_contents('input.txt');
$inputData = explode("\n", trim($list));

function main ( $inputData ) {
   foreach ($inputData as $row) {
    if (empty($row)) break;

    //explode row
    $p = explode(",", $row);

    // retrieve bin, amount and currency
    $p2 = explode(':', $p[0]);
    $currency = trim($p2[1], '"}');

    // Class which needs a mock up because it requires API call
    $calApi = new CalculatorAPI(); 
    $result =$calApi->getFinalResult($currency);

    echo $result;
    print "\n";
   }
}

main( $inputData );
```

Note that: in `input.txt` I have `{"currency":"EUR"}...` to get currency list.

Now I need to write some code for `PHPUnit test`:: here is test file

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__."/../app.php";

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AppTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testApp() : void
    {
        $calAPI = $this->createStub(CalculatorAPI::class);
        $calAPI->method('getFinalResult')
            ->willReturn(1);

        $result = main($this->data, $calAPI);

        $this->assertEquals(1, $result);
    }

}
```

when I run this it executes the file. How do I write code for `raw PHP`?
Also, I need to run the test offline though it requires an API call.

Comment: Perhaps if you test it as though it's any other CLI program (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700653/how-do-i-test-a-command-line-program-with-phpunit).

Comment: @NigelRen .. Its working. But this is not  a proper way,

Comment: @NigelRen I need to run the test offline too. and it required an API call

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your `foreach` code into a function, say `myForeach` in order to prevent it execution at `require_once __DIR__."/../app.php";` time.

Then from your test you have to run your `myForeach` function. In your test you have to catch the output of your `myForeach` function. After you catch it you have to compare it vs the expected value you want to see the function produce in success case.

Then your your `AppTest::test()` might look like the following:

```php
$actual = myForeach();
$this->assertEquals('my expected foreach return value', $actual);
```

This is only for the case when `myForeach` explicitly returns value (and it does not in your case whether intentionally or not). Now if you are expecting `myForeach` to output in the console instead of explicitly returning some value (which can be a case if you TDD a e.g. CLI utility) your test would look like this:

```php
// Wrap your `myForeach` function into something special
// to catch its console output made with `print`
ob_start();
myForeach();
$actual = ob_get_clean();

// Now you have all your output from the function in $actual variable
// and you can assert with PHPUnit if it contains the expected string
$this->assertStringContainsString('my expected foreach return value', $actual);
```

Some links: PHP output buffering [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), PHPUnit available [assertions](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/assertions.html)

Comment: I can not use the function because the need to run `php app.php input.txt` from the terminal .. please guide

Comment: I tried your way ... it fails with the same problem -- I need a mock for this one.

Comment: @SelimReza you do not need a mock. You can use a function. Just pass the `$list` argument to it? What particular problem does it fail with?

Comment: @SelimReza divide the top snippet into 2 classes: `Command` would accept the file name from [CLI arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)   `Calculator->execute(array $list)` would loop over the file content and call `CalculatorAPI` and put the results into e.g. array. Then return that array. Then command class would print the returned result.

Comment: @SelimReza now to tests. First could be `CalculatorTest`. There you test `Calculator->execute($list)` result. You can inject the fake `CalculatorAPI` class instance like this `Calculator->execute(array $list, $calculatorAPI)`. You make the fake yourself. Just make a class that pretend to do what real `CalcualtorAPI` should. In you tests you inject the fake, in your `Command` class you inject your real `CalculatorAPI` class instance.

Comment: I have updated the code ( my question ) according to your instruction. please check and update your solution that will help me

Comment: @SelimReza remove `main( $inputData )` from the top code snippet. This is the culprit of why your code executes at `require_once` time. Refactor your `main` function to take 2 parameters to match this line in the test `$result = main($this->data, $calAPI);`. As well if your decision is to `echo` results in `main` refer to my answer to refactor your test. You cannot use  `$result = main($this->data, $calAPI);`assignment as your `main` does not return anything.